# Excel - Getting displayed names different from actual names

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm wondering if there was any way to get a displayed text to be different from an actual text. For example, HOMEDEPOT2294 would get displayed as Home Depot. (I'd need more than just removing numbers, or reformatting existing cells - I'm hoping to get a direct A gets displayed as B when printing.)

I'd like to avoid the solution of using a new sheet, having the new sheet reference the old sheet completely except for the column with the name change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a ton of these text translations , you can use vlookup from another file.

e.g. Insert column to right of one with these entries.

**=Vlookup(**left arrow  **,** point to ***array*** with 1st column contain same names **, 2,0)**  where 2 is 2nd column of array for replacement name )

Original file is only edited with extra column.

Array must look like ***(filename)$A$1:$Z99*** 
so you can copy cell formula down to highlit cells and paste

then hide old column

Comment: Not sure how I didn't think of this, thank you! I'm wondering if that's the only work-around, and if there's really no way to get different text displayed over - I think it would be cool if it's doable

Comment: not unless you are talking about data entry, it remembers what you start typing and one can auto-complete